# Emulating a character device from userspace

Tags: kernel, drivers, devices, c

We are currently working on building a system for data visualisation for different sensors.

To make development of the Linux application possible we would need to emulate the behaviour of the different character devices as the device drivers and the hardware design aren't done yet.

So is there a way to receive the system calls (open(), read(), write()...) on a specific file inside a, for instance, C program that is also run from userspace?

```
                                   read()
(Userspace Application/Database) <========= (~/mydev) <===== (dummy_driver)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [cuse](https://lwn.net/Articles/308445/) *Character Device in Userspace* which is a part of the [fuse](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse) library, available as a package in most systems. An example "driver" is [cuse.c](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/master/example/cuse.c). 
When you compile and run this example as:

```
sudo ./cuse -f --name=mydevice
```

it creates `/dev/mydevice` and receives all the open, close, read, write, ioctl calls on it.
To "unmount" the device (in fuse terminology), just kill the process.

The example is probably not distributed, so to compile, download (or git clone) the [zip](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse), change to the `libfuse/example` directory, and compile as shown in the C file:

```
gcc -Wall cuse.c $(pkg-config fuse --cflags --libs) -o cuse -I.
```

You may need to install a `fuse-devel` package or similar for this to work. If you need to implement more ioctl's, check out this [link](https://bitbucket.org/hetii/cusetty) given **as a comment to the answer** of this [stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40445934/5008284) question.

Simpler alternatives to consider are a pseudo-tty [pty](https://linux.die.net/man/7/pty), or [tty0tty](https://github.com/freemed/tty0tty) which is a kernel module that joins two serial ports together.

Comment: Thanks you so much, fuse/cuse seems to be the perfect solution for our needs!

Comment: Thank you! There also seems to be a Python implementation available: https://github.com/piranna/cusepy